# ADT get BufferOverflowException in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms

I'm using Eclipse Juno with ADT to develop android applications and eclipse is showing the following error every minute:

```
[2013-04-03 17:59:46 - ddms] null
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:182)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:628)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

When this message pops, eclipse open a terminal and it overlaps my available code edit area.

How to fix it? Stop eclipse to show this message is also useful.

Comment: i am getting this on Ubuntu with Eclipse ADT when trying to run sample  application on Nexus 5 :(

Answer (score 2):

Does not really help without any code, but it could be related to exceeding the limits set on some kind of loop or data structure. I think you can use ctrl-x or ctrl-c to stop certain processes in eclipse. You can also make a setting in preferences to have the errors piped into a log file.

Comment: At this point, pipe erros to a log file would be an acceptable solution, since the error stops pop up the editor area. But... how to pipe erros to a log? Will this pipe all erros messages, or can I pipe just ddms erros?

Comment: yeah unfortunately I think it will pipe all errors to a log. However it probably isn't that difficult to extract only the ddms errors from the log.

Comment: I could not pipe just that specific error. Since your answer provide such information, I'll be glad in accept it as a correct one.